# Class-AB Amplifier Excessive Heat

Tags: amplifier, overheat

I'm using a TI TPA6017A2 as a pre-amp for an in-car audio application and it's getting excessively hot, to the point where the IC burns my finger when touched if I set the input volume to max. Beyond that, I can *hear* the music being emitted from the IC which is extremely disconcerting.

My design has a thermal pad with thermal vias and the IC has been soldered down to that pad per the datasheet recommendations.

If I lower the input gain, I can alleviate the issue, but this isn't a bug I want in my final design.

As far as the layout, I have duplicated the design of the evaluation module, which also gets hot, but not the extent that my design does.

The only deviation from the reference/EVM design that I have is that I have tied the negative output channels together directly, since the wiring harness expects a single negative line being fed in. Could this be the cause of my issues? What exactly is causing the IC to resonate?

It should be noted that the output audio has no distortion, but the thermal threshold is being hit and the IC is shutting itself down at times.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Layout]

Comment: You probably need to submit the exact schematics of you wiring of output channels.

Comment: The singing IC is interesting. Can you record a little video with sound by using a phone and insert a link for us to see and hear it. Close all other sound sources and move the phone gradually towards the singing IC.

Comment: "I can hear the music being emitted from the IC" sounds like a feature to me

Comment: @user287001 - Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR1OLeinKeM If you turn up your sound high enough, you'll hear the rhythmic beating of the drums.

Comment: thanks for the effort. The effect is very weak and is badly covered by noise.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I tried as best I could to minimize background noise.

Comment: it can also exist only beyond 10kHz. Many people, including me,  have destroyed their ability to hear something at higher frequencies without jet dB levels. It happens easily - for ex. work unprotected in a noisy factory, shoot a day with poor protection etc... or get old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do **that**.

The [TPA6017A2](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa6017a2.pdf) has a kind of bridge output.  With the negative sides tied together and to ground, you are creating a mess of a short circuit.

The wonder isn't that it's hot and noisy.

The wonder is that is hasn't just burned out or exploded.

Comment: The more you know :). How would you suggest I output both negative sides to a single output? My gut says you're going to suggest a non-BTL amp, but I'm not an EE, so I don't know if there's a better fix here. Thanks!

Comment: Use R+ and L+ and ground.  Leave R- and L- open.   Might work, might not do so well. Or, use something else as  preamplifier.  I don't understand why you are using a power amp as a preamplifier.

Comment: @JRE don't you know, more power = more better

Comment: @JRE - The amplifier expects a 2W per channel input from the pre-amp, which is why I chose this IC. I'll give using the GND for the GND a try. The EVM actually has ground posts between the +/- for each channel, so I assume this configuration is supported.

Comment: You won't get 2W single ended (one output against ground.) The amp uses the bridge configuration to get 2W from 5V.  Single ended you'll probably get more lije 0.5W.

Comment: @JRE - Interesting, thank you! A somewhat related question: Are three wire analog audio inputs always single ended? Seems like they would have to be, if differential outputs cannot have their negative terminals tied.

Comment: Yep.  If you have right, left, and ground then it's single ended.  Lots of stuff works that way.